# How to save the makeline information (coordinates) in Fiji (imageJ) which comes from the user

Tags: imagej, fiji, imagej-macro

I have a macro in Fiji where I am using the waitForUser("For creating the plot", "Make a line along the diameter of the cell and press OK") code and I want to save the coordinates of the line drawn by user, can someone please help as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
getSelectionCoordinates( x, y );
print( "start: x="+x[0]+"; y="+y[0] );
print( "end: x="+x[1]+"; y="+y[1] );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?